# 'Pygments gem or one of its dependencies isn't installed' error message

Tags: ruby, node.js, jekyll

I tried to install this starter project: https://github.com/shakyShane/jekyll-gulp-sass-browser-sync

I have the latest Ruby and Node.js installed. I followed the setup instructions for this starter project: installed `jekyll`, `gulp`, ran the `npm install` command and after that `gulp`. And when I ran `gulp` I got this error message:

> Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have pygments 
>       or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll 
>       need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 
>       'cannot load such file -- pygments' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources 
>       at http://jekyllrb.com/help/! 
>       Liquid Exception: pygments in C:/work/Web/MySite/_posts/2014-04-20-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown
>                ERROR: YOUR SITE COULD NOT BE BUILT:
>                       ------------------------------------
>                       pygments

I tried to install pygments manually: `gem install pygments.rb`, but it didn't help.

I'm new to Ruby and Jekyll... What went wrong here and how can it be fixed?

**UPDATE**
This is the error message from `gem install pygments.rb`:

> Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
>       Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>       ERROR:  Error installing pygments.rb:
>           ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> current directory: C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.2.1/ext/yajl
>   C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160811-6768-1qhknd7.rb extconf.rb
>   creating Makefile
>
> current directory: C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.2.1/ext/yajl
>   make "DESTDIR=" clean
>
> current directory: C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.2.1/ext/yajl
>   make "DESTDIR="
>   generating yajl-x64-mingw32.def
>   compiling yajl.c
>   yajl.c: In function 'yajl_status_to_string':
>   yajl.c:61:1: warning: visibility attribute not supported in this configuration; ignored [-Wattributes]
>
> ...more of these `yajl_...` visibility attribute not supported messages...
>
> c:/ruby23-x64/devkit/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/dllcrt2.o: file not recognized: File trun
>   cated
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [yajl.so] Error 1
>
> make failed, exit code 2
>
> Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.2.1 for inspection.
>
> Results logged to C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/yajl-ruby-1.2.1/gem_make.out

Comment: Show the error from gem install pygments

Comment: @maxpleaner I updated my question with this error. Thanks!

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/issues/207), seems to be the same issue.

Comment: @maxpleaner Seems very similar, but still doesn't solve the problem that I have... Any suggestions how to fix it? Thank you again!

Comment: did you follow the suggestions from that page? look at the comment that suggests `libcrypt-devel`

Comment: @maxpleaner I found a solution, will post an answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

OK, after a very long time I finally found a solution to the problem I had. Here's what I did:

1. Completely uninstalled all gems.
2. Uninstalled Ruby DevTools
3. Uninstalled Ruby
4. Re-installed Ruby
5. Re-installed Ruby DevTools (downloaded it again, apparently my previous download had corrupted files) , changed config.yml to include `- C:/Ruby23-x64`
6. Re-installed pygments.rb (this time it went well, without any errors)
7. Installed Python (very important)
8. Edited Gulp's _config.yml and changed default highlighter from pygments to rouge
9. Installed redcarpet gem `gem install redcarpet`
10. Ran `gulp` again and this time it finally worked as expected!